# How to add new element based on the condition in the input xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

i need to insert new element based on th input xml element value condition.please help me.

i need to check for policy/transactionSplitTrans/sourceSystemCd/code='SCBP' if true i nedd to add element underlyingPolicyOperationalDatabaseCd/code under policy\ tag.

input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<policies>
    <policy>
        <policyKey>
            <policyNbr>004567</policyNbr>
            <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
            <policyID>54545</policyID>
            <policyFormCd>
                <code>669</code>
            </policyFormCd>
        </policyKey>
        <transactionSplitTrans>
            <sourceSystemCd>
                <code>SCBP</code>
            </sourceSystemCd>
        </transactionSplitTrans>
    </policy> 
</policies>
```

Expected O/p:

```
<policies>
    <policy>
        <policyKey>
            <policyNbr>004567</policyNbr>
            <policyEffectiveDt>2014-11-14</policyEffectiveDt>
            <policyID>54545</policyID>
            <policyFormCd>
                <code>669</code>
            </policyFormCd>
        </policyKey>
        <transactionSplitTrans>
            <sourceSystemCd>
                <code>SCBP</code>
            </sourceSystemCd>
        </transactionSplitTrans>
        <underlyingPolicyOperationalDatabaseCd>
            <code>SCBP</code>
        </underlyingPolicyOperationalDatabaseCd>
    </policy> 
</policies>
```

Tried xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd" 
    extension-element-prefixes="dp str xsd xsi ps dpconfig pol" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="dp dpconfig xsi soap xsd xsi str pol dpconfig xsl a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="underlyingPolicyOperationalDatabaseCd">underlyingPolicyOperationalDatabaseCd</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="code">code</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="Copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//policy">
        <xsl:call-template name="Copy"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./transactionSplitTrans/sourceSystemCd[code='SCBP']">
                <xsl:element name="{$underlyingPolicyOperationalDatabaseCd}">
                    <xsl:element name="{$code}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'SCBP'" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is an identity template, a template to match the target node, and a condition under the target node that will insert the additional nodes if the condition is true. Such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="transactionSplitTrans">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="descendant::code='SCBP' or preceding-sibling::policyKey/policyFormCd/code='UB'">
            <underlyingPolicyOperationalDatabaseCd>
                <code>SCBP</code>
            </underlyingPolicyOperationalDatabaseCd>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Lamsen. theres one more condition in my requirement.If above condition is not true i need to check for policy/policyKey/policyFormCd/code='UB' i need to output same underlyingPolicyOperationalDatabaseCd/code='SCBP' under policy Tag.

Comment: I have edited my answer. In the future, please include all conditions in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lamsen.Sorry for inconvinience.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow! If you find this answer useful, please tick the check mark just below the arrowheads on the left (to make it appear green). This way, other users can know that this is the accepted answer.